# Select multiple distinct rows from table SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, select, greatest-n-per-group

I am attempting to select distinct (last updated) rows from a table in my database. I am trying to get the last updated row for each "Sub section". However I cannot find a way to achieve this.

The table looks like:

```
ID    | Name   |LastUpdated                  | Section    | Sub    |

1     | Name1  | 2013-04-07 16:38:18.837     | 1          | 1      |
2     | Name2  | 2013-04-07 15:38:18.837     | 1          | 2      |
3     | Name3  | 2013-04-07 12:38:18.837     | 1          | 1      |
4     | Name4  | 2013-04-07 13:38:18.837     | 1          | 3      |
5     | Name5  | 2013-04-07 17:38:18.837     | 1          | 3      |
```

What I am trying to get my SQL Statement to do is return rows:

1, 2, and 5.

They are distinct for the Sub, and the most recent.

I have tried:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Sub, LastUpdated, Name 
FROM TABLE 
WHERE LastUpdated = (SELECT MAX(LastUpdated) FROM TABLE WHERE Section = 1)
```

Which only returns the distinct row for the most recent updated Row. Which makes sense.

I have googled what I am trying, and checked relevant posts on here. However not managed to find one which really answers what I am trying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `row_number()` window function to assign numbers for each partition of rows with the same value of Sub.  Using `order by LastUpdated desc`, the row with row number one will be the latest row:

```
select  *
from    (
        select  row_number() over (
                    partition by Sub 
                    order by LastUpdated desc) as rn
        ,       *
        from    YourTable
        ) as SubQueryAlias
where   rn = 1
```

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I was trying to figure out.

Answer (score -1):

Wouldn't it be enough to use group by?

```
SELECT DISTINCT MIN(Sub), MAX(LastUpdated), MIN(NAME) FROM TABLE GROUP BY Sub Where Section = 1
```

Comment: In your query, `min(name)` might not belong to the same row as `max(LastUpdated)`.